# I have encounterd a problem when trying to execute the command npm run in vs code

Tags: npm-start

when I try to run npm start command I get this error[How the error looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTesC.png)
I am using a plugin in the markdown app Obsidian. The plugin https://github.com/oleeskild/digitalgarden

How can I fix this error?

I have already tryed npm rebuild --verbose sharp, but it did not fix it.

Comment: can you post that error on your question vs a png?

Comment: The png is in the "How the error looks" hypertext

Comment: right. don't post it as a png. makes it easier if we can just copy and paste it so we can look look it up and assist in solving.